# Heat-shrink for electrical insulation of a metal hinge

Tags: electrical, insulation

I have a metal door hinge which is part of a trap for a Physics experiment (measuring 'g' by free fall). I want to cover the hinge so that it is electrically insulated. I was thinking of using heat-shrink to do this.
The hinges is 65mm wide.

[image]

Is heat-shrink a good idea or is there a better way to do insulate the metal hinge?

Also, do I need heat-shrink tubing of 130mm diameter of shrink ratio 2:1?

When working the magnet holds the hinge up and then the ball bearing hits the hinge and breaks the circuit connection between the hinge and the horizontal metal. Breaking the circuit will stop the timer which starts when the ball is released by an electromagnet. So the time to fall is measured.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Heatsink looks as a nice solution, assuming the narrow part of the hinge is > 33,  mm, otherwise you mag need a 1:3 shrink ratio.

Comment: Why do you need to insulate it at all? If you really do need to would a couple of layers of insulation tape not do the trick?

Comment: If you insulate the hinge then it won't be able to make a circuit to be broken. The wood should do a good job of insulating the hinge from the horizontal bar when the circuit is broken.

Comment: What exactly needs to be insulated from what? Also, steel hinges are not going to give you reliable electrical contact in the first place. I would recommend adding a proper [microswitch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miniature_snap-action_switch) to the setup.

Comment: @Huisman yes the narrow part or the thickness is only about 4mm, the width where the hinge fixes to the box is 65mm. 1:3 shrink would then mean the unshrunk material would need a tube diameter of about 140mm or so. Thanks

Comment: @Transistor It needs to be insulated from humans being able to be in contact with the metal. So the horizontal non hinge part also needs shrink-wrap on it. But obviously where they come in contact would have the heat-shrink cut away. There could be potentially as much as 24V across the metal but more likely 12V. Thanks Thanks

Comment: @AndrewMorton Where the two metal make contact the heat-shrink would have to be cut away in order for them to make contact there. Thanks

Comment: @DaveTweed I was thinking of a microswitch but did not know what they were called. This would be a very good idea as it would mean the whole hinge and other piece of metal may not necessarily all need to be electrified. Thanks

Comment: 24 V would be considered safe for human contact if the supply is only capable of an amp or two.

Comment: @Transistor Ok that is good to know thanks